# How to fix libxml2 vulneribilty

Tags: security, web-server

I am using ubuntu 12.04, as per ubuntu http://www.ubuntu.com/usn/usn-1447-1/ libxml2 needs to be patched, how can i achieve it without distro upgrade

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The procedure is covered in the page you linked:

> To update your system, please follow these instructions:
>   https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Security/Upgrades.

Run `apt-get update` then `apt-get upgrade`.